# Getting number of rows grouped by date

Tags: r, dataframe, histogram

I have the following data frame:

[image]

and I want to create a histogram displaying the number of tweets (number of rows) per day(column created_at). How could I get the nrow grouped by date ?

Many Thanks

Comment: please add minimal data example

Comment: Feel free to accept one of the answers below and/or vote them up, if you are satisfied. :-)

Answer (score 3):

In one method chain:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(date) %>% 
  mutate(tweets_no = n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = date)) + 
  geom_histogram(stat = "count", fill = "blue")
```

Or simply using the original data:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = date)) + 
  geom_histogram(stat = "count", fill = "blue")
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `count`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   count(date)
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(date=c("2020/05/07", "2020/05/07", "2020/05/08"), 
             text=c("tweet_a", "tweet_b", "tweet_c"))
```

Comment: Your solutions are always so simple and awesome. My thoughts are always too complicated...

Comment: @MartinGal thank you for the comments.  I would say that don't think negative about yourself.   Have a positive attitude to beat me and you will surely beat me.

Answer (score 2):

Posting a picture of data isn't usally a good way to ask questions.

I try to answer your question with some sample data.

```r
df <- data.frame(date=c("2020/05/07", "2020/05/07", "2020/05/08"), 
                 text=c("tweet_a", "tweet_b", "tweet_c"))
df %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  summarise(n=n())
```

gives you

```r
  date           n
  <fct>      <int>
1 2020/05/07     2
2 2020/05/08     1
```

I suppose that's what you are looking for?